# Infopath + Class Libraray + Webservice = could not find default endpoint element that references contract 

Tags: web-services, infopath, class-library, infopath-2007

Ok, this question has been answered many times. But not for this scenario.
I created new 'Infopath Form Template' project, added new Class Library project to the solution and then created a Web Service proxy in that Class Library.
When I try to create an instance of the Web Service client proxy I get this exception.

The usual solution is to copy the app.config into the Windows/Web application, but what about Infopath Form Template? I tried just adding the app.config to the project, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked for me: I created a solutions which contains only the Class Library project with the service.
I edited the Form code using VSTA project (not form template project in regular Visual Studio), and copied there the app.config.

Works :)